# Async Image Downloading in UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone

I am making my UIcollectionviewcell to download the image async But only the last image is coming for the last cell. Below is my code

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  self.collectionViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSMutableDictionary *temperoryDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self.weatherArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSString *imageURL = [[[temperoryDictionary valueForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"value"];

 [self downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {

   if (succeeded) {

       self.collectionViewCell.weatherImage.image= image;

    }
}];

return self.collectionViewCell;
}


- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image))completionBlock{


   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
                           if (!error)
                           {
                               UIImage *imageAsync = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

                               completionBlock(YES,imageAsync);

                           } else {

                               completionBlock(NO,nil);
                           }
                       }];
}
```

I don't know what error i am making.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of `self.collectionViewCell`, you should use `__block UICollectionViewCell * cell`:

```
    - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        __block UICollectionViewCell * cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSMutableDictionary *temperoryDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self.weatherArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        NSString *imageURL = [[[temperoryDictionary valueForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"value"];

         [self downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {

           if (succeeded) {

               cell.weatherImage.image= image;

            }
        }];
        return cell;
    }
```

For custom cell, using `__block CustomClass * cell`. `CustomClass` is the class of custom cell.

Comment: `return cell;` not  `return self.collectionViewCell;`

Comment: I am using a custom cell... with the image view.  if i will use  your solution.. How my custom cell's property will get my image...

Comment: @AnujVats I edited my answer. Please try it. Thank you

Comment: I'd recommend checking the actual index of the cell before setting the image, as the loading might finish after the cell has been scrolled off screen and been reused for another index path.

Comment: Thanks anhtu... that solve the problem mate... can you please brief the mistake... i new to iOS

Comment: My answer isn't the best (as @mbo42 mentioned). But it can solve your problem. With your code, assume you have 2 cells. `self.collectionViewCell` point to cell 1 and call `downloadImageWithURL`. Then the `self.collectionViewCell` point to cell 2. But `downloadImageWithURL` doesn't finish yet. So when `downloadImageWithURL` finished. The cell 2 gets the image of the cell 1 (because the  `self.collectionViewCell` point to cell 2 now). So the cell 1 won't get any image.

Answer (score 0):

`self.collectionViewCell` will have only 1 cell referenced. Replace it will a local variable `UICollectionViewCell * collectionViewCell`

Comment: then how i am get the data source for my custom UIcollectionviewcell

Comment: just return `collectionViewCell` local variable. You dont need a member variable.

Comment: The Answer mentioned by @anhtu should solve the probelm

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need pointer for the last cell, as it most likely will be the last cell tableView has asked for when the images has finished loading.

Instead, try this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSInteger currentTag = indexPath.row;
    cell.tag = currentTag;

    NSMutableDictionary *temperoryDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[self.weatherArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    NSString *imageURL = [[[temperoryDictionary valueForKey:@"weatherIconUrl"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"value"];

    __weak __typeof(cell) weakCell = cell;
    [self downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL] completionBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, UIImage *image) {
        if (succeeded && weakCell.tag == currentTag) {
            weakCell.weatherImage.image = image;
        }
    }];

}
```

This keeps a weak pointer to the current cell, and when finished loading the image it will check if the cell's tag (indexPath.row) is the same, and in that case set the image.

Comment: Eh... it keeps a weak local pointer for the loading block, not the ViewController... There's no need for the ViewController to keep a pointer to a cell at all